# GatsbyImage not working in production site (Pulling data from WP CMS)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, image, graphql, gatsby

EDIT: Issue fixed by moving public build files to server's root directory.

I'm using Wordpress CMS to set featured images to posts, and trying to render those images in Gatsby.

So far, it works when viewing the site in development (using 'gatsby develop') but when I build the actual static site (with 'gatsby build'), the featured images are not shown.

Example of how I'm rendering the featured images:

```
<GatsbyImage image={getImage(post.node.featuredImage.node.localFile)} alt={post.node.title}/> : 
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x800" alt={post.node.title || ""}/>}
```

And this the GraphQL query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allWpPost {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          featuredImage {
            node {
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  gatsbyImageData(
                    placeholder: DOMINANT_COLOR
                    formats: [JPG, WEBP, AVIF]
                    quality: 90
                  )
                }
              }
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This seems to be the recommended way to render dynamic images from CMS according to the docs. Using [gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image) and [gatsby-transformer-sharp.](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-sharp/)

```
The getImage() function is an optional helper to make your code easier to read. It takes a File and returns file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData, which can be passed to the GatsbyImage component.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just using:

```
<GatsbyImage image={post.node.featuredImage.node.localFile.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt={post.node.title}/>
```

Comment: I just did. Same resullt :(

Comment: So your build command is not downloading the assets. Can you debug a little bit more?

Comment: Well I debugged as much as I know, can't seem to find anything wrong. Interestingly, dynamic placeholders work when I set "placeholder: blurred" or "dominantcolor" in gatsbyImageData query.  I actually can see the correct dominant color, or a super blurred image, depending on the settings.

Comment: Screenhost of the render: https://i.imgur.com/2uKO9wN.png

Comment: Build console shows some warnings, no errors. it is getting image object for posts and pages that have feauted image set.

` {
    featuredImage: { node: [Object] }
  },`

while if it is not set, it shows "featuredImage: null"

browser console shows a bunch of missing assets: https://i.imgur.com/q9PgyUL.png

Comment: Figured it out. It was trivial, my bad. 
I had the static site files set in a sub-root directory of my local server, while the gatsby-generated image paths didn't account for that and were getting 404s. 
Thanks for your help.